# German Truck Simulator on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, wine

I want to know if is there any way to play German Truck Simulator in Ubuntu 12.04?
With Wine, it doesn't works. (The installation worked fine, but when I launch GTS, it says me this:

```
German Truck Simulator unable to find any graphic card driver on your system. 
Please install the correct driver to your graphic card and try start the game again.
```

If I try to install the Windows drivers, it says me this:

```
There is no graphic card on your PC which is comptible with this driver. 
Please install the correct drivers and start the installer again.
```

So, is there a Linux version of GTS? (or a .deb package?)

Answer (score 5):

> Answer to the question

German Truck Simulator works under Wine with a [platinum rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11217). So does [Euro Trucks Simulator](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20251&iTestingId=64962),  [18 Wheels of Steel: Across America](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6159), [18 Wheels of Steel: American Long Haul](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6345), [18 Wheels of Steel: Convoy](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3499), [18 Wheels of Steel: Extreme Trucker](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11478) and [18 Wheels of Steel: Pedal to the Metal](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3075). So you should be able to get these working.

2 of the games do work native under Linux using Steam: [Scania Truck Driving Simulator, Euro Truck Simulator 2](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197969693498/myworkshopfiles/?section=greenlight).

> Extra about Wine

Since all of the games are platinum you do need to fix this problem inside Wine. But it depends alot on the game specific what to do. For instance `driconf` is used for 3d acceleration.
I would suggest to start with `Play on Linux` and install it from there; those installation scripts tend to fix alot of problems out of the box.

---

UPDATE:

Euro Truck Simulator 2 beta for Linux has been in closed beta testing for a few days and today it's available as a **non free** public beta for all Linux users, **exclusively through Steam**. More information on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/euro-truck-simulator-2-game-for-linux.html) and [SCS software blog](http://blog.scssoft.com/2013/04/public-linux-beta-of-euro-truck.html).